# Print PDF Hidden In C#

Tags: c#, pdf

I am try to print a PDF document by AdobeReader process. The print must be hidden for the user.

I read all the possible solutions to this problem and wrote the code as indicated but in my case it does not work.

The code is as follow:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.Verb = "printto";
info.FileName = segnToPrint;
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.Arguments = "\"" + stmp + "\"";
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = info;
p.Start();
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
p.WaitForInputIdle();
```

How can i solve this problem?

thanks

Comment: Haven't tested it, but worth a try: [this article](https://vishalsbsinha.wordpress.com/2014/05/06/how-to-programmatically-c-net-print-a-pdf-file-directly-to-the-printer/)

Comment: Or use a third party component, like [this](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfnet/Printing+PDF+File+to+Default+Printer+using+Printer+and+Page+Settings+(Facades))

Comment: Adobe Reader does everything it can to prevent this, see the comments on [this post](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1042132) on the Acrobat SDK forums.